# Solving $(z+px)^{2}=q$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

> Solve the PDE: $(z+px)^{2}=q$ with the usual notation $p=z_{x}$ and $q=z_{y}$.

---

Here is what I have tried using Charpit's method:

$$\begin{aligned}f=(z+px)^{2}-q\end{aligned}$$

So that we get the auxiliary equations as:

$$\frac{\mathrm dx}{-2x(z+px)}=\frac{\mathrm dy}{1}=\frac{\mathrm dz}{-2px(z+px)+q}=\frac{\mathrm dp}{4p(z+px)}=\frac{\mathrm dq}{2q(z+px)}$$

So that $p=aq^{2}$ and $xq=b$. Now I'm unsure of how to proceed, since I am supposed to solve $\mathrm dz=p\mathrm dx +q\mathrm dy$, but it does not become a complete differential. Any hints would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What partial differential equation ?? I only see a quadratic expression equal to something called $\;q\;$ ...

Answer (score 1):

You found $z_y=\frac{b}{x}$ that one integrates wrt $y$ :
$$z=\frac{b}{x}y+f(x)$$
$$z_x=-\frac{b}{x^2}+f'(x)$$
Putting them in the PDE :
$$\left(\left(\frac{b}{x}+f(x)\right)+\left(-\frac{b}{x^2}+f'(x) \right)x \right)^2=\frac{b}{x}$$
$$\left(f(x)+xf'(x) \right)^2=\frac{b}{x}$$
Solving leads to :
$$f(x)=2\sqrt{\frac{b}{x}}+\frac{c}{x}$$
$$\boxed{z=\frac{b}{x}y+2\sqrt{\frac{b}{x}}+\frac{c}{x}}$$
You also found $z_x=a\left(\frac{b}{x}\right)^2$ that one integrates wrt $x$ :
$$z=-\frac{ab^2}{x}+g(y)=\frac{A}{x}+g(y)$$
$z_y=g'(y)$ . Putting them into the PDE leads to :
$$\left(\left(-\frac{ab^2}{x}+g(y) \right)+x\left(a\left(\frac{b}{x}\right)^2 \right) \right)^2=g'(y)$$
$$g(y)^2=g'(y)$$
Solving leads to :
$$g(y)=\frac{1}{c-y}$$
$$\boxed{z=-\frac{A}{x}+\frac{1}{C-y}}$$
This is another solution of the PDE different from the first solution above.

Note : Don't make a confusion in putting the different $p$ and $q$ respectif in a same $dz=p.dx+q.dy$ This would lead to wrong results.